# how to use tika for extracting the content from ppt?

Tags: apache-tika

fellow programmers!I extract a ppt file with using tika,which has only plain text.However,the result that tika give a content type is a jpg format!So my question is how to deal with it for I only want that case to be detected as a plain text type.

Comment: How are you calling Apache Tika? Without any code showing how you call Tika, or more details on what you're seeing, we can't really help much...

Comment: I use tika-app-1.16.jar to do it.

Comment: What arguments are you passing to the Tika App to get your content out?

Comment: Sorry,i use tikacli to deal with a ppt file.It's "java -jar .\tika-app-1.16.jar --extract .\fulltext.pptx".

Comment: Do you want to Extract all the embedded resources? Or get the plain text form of the contents?

Comment: i want to get all the text that maybe in the embedded resources.

Comment: Do you have Tesseract OCR enabled? You'll need that to get text from PDFs, Images etc

Comment: emmm,i can get some text from pdf by using tika.And now i want to know how to get whole text content from ppt file.

Answer (score 0):

I change some source code in the tika,so I can get what content I want.In this way,I extract the ppt file and get the right result.